# Excluding a list of directories from Find

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I am using rsyncrypto to backup a few of my user directories.  I want to exclude some subdirectories from the encryption. I read that the best way to do this is to pipe the output of find to rsyncrypto.

Here's a find command that excludes directories named tmp:

```
find ~/Documents -type d -not \( -name tmp -prune \)
```

I have six or seven such directories to exclude. Is there a simple way for me to enumerate all of them in my find command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
find ~/Documents -type d ! \( -regex '.*/\(foo\|bar\|baz\)/?$' -prune \)
```

Keep in mind that the regex matches the whole directory/file structure not just the base name.

Answer (score 1):

`find ~/ -type d \! -name folder1 -and \! -name folder2`