# Problems excluding directories in a Linux find

Tags: linux, find

Trying to exclude a set of directories from a find is driving me nuts!  What I want to do is look for all .java files in a directory tree, but ignore all those in test directories.  So, I've tried:

```
find . -name "*.java" -not -path "test"
```

and

```
find . -name "*.java" -path "test" -prune
```

and several variations thereof.  However - depending on the variation - I either get all the java files (including those in test directories), or none of them.  I looked at other questions here on SU (e.g. [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/207034/why-doesnt-find-prune-the-way-i-think-it-should) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/178185/excluding-a-list-of-directories-from-find)), but either they don't address my situation, or I'm missing something.

I'm using gnu find 4.2.27 (fwiw, on centos 5.5 w/ gnu bash 3.2.25).

Edit:  Sorry, I should have originally specified that I need to do a

```
-exec grep blah {} \;
```

so piping through grep -v won't work for me in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
find -path '*/test/*' -prune -o -name '*.java' -exec grep blah {} \;
```

Comment: `-path '*/test/*' -prune` is simpler expressed as `-name test -prune`. If you replace the `\;` by a `+`, the `grep` command will be executed fewer times, and will (almost always) show file names on matches. If you add `-H` after `grep`, the matches will always include file names.

Comment: @Gilles:  Thanks for the excellent input; someone local to me suggested -name test -prune, which does work for this case.  However, I can imagine that if the search was different using -name test -prune would exclude files named test if there were any.

Comment: @GreenMatt: Yes. Here the issue doesn't arise since `test` and `*.java` don't intersect. Otherwise, both cases make sense. If you only want to exclude directories named test, use `find -name test -type d -prune -o …`.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidating the above-mentioned tips, this searches for PHP files recursively but excludes several directories and then zips them up.

> find -name locallibs -prune -o -name libs -prune -o -name wiki -prune -o -name tmp -prune -o -name '*.php' -exec zip all.zip {} \;